# How to resize a QLabel with pixmap inside a QScrollArea?

Tags: qt, qlabel, qscrollarea

I have a designer form (Dialog without Buttons template) containing `QScrollArea` and 2 `QPushButton` objects inside a vertical layout. I want to set `QLabel` with a pixmap inside the `QScrollArea`.

Here is my code:

*In the constructor of `Viewer`*

```
m_imageLabel = new QLabel;
m_imageLabel->setPixmap(image);
m_imageLabel->setScaledContents(true);

ui->scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(m_imageLabel);
ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
```

*the slot*

```
void Viewer::on_zoomInButton_clicked()
{
    m_imageLabel->resize(m_scaleFactor * m_imageLabel->pixmap()->size());
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when the `zoomInButton` is clicked, nothing happens.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Cause

By using [`ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) you allow the scroll area to resize the widget automatically:

> If this property is set to true, the scroll area will automatically resize the widget in order to avoid scroll bars where they can be avoided, or to take advantage of extra space.

Furthermore, you calculate the new size of the `QLabel` in a wrong way, i.e. you use the size of its `pixmap`, which in turn remains constant.

## Solution

In order to achieve the desired effect, I would suggest you to:

1. Explicitly set the [`widgetResizable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html#widgetResizable-prop) property to `false`:

   ```
   ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);
   ```
2. Make the new size of the `QLabel` dependent on its old size, instead of the size of its `pixmap`:

   ```
   m_imageLabel->resize(m_scaleFactor * m_imageLabel->size());
   ```

## Example

Here is a minimal example I have prepared for you in order to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QLabel>

struct Viewer : public QWidget
{
    explicit Viewer(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QWidget(parent)
    {
        auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        auto *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
        auto *btnZoomIn = new QPushButton(tr("Zoom In"), this);
        auto *btnZoomOut = new QPushButton(tr("Zoom Out"), this);
        auto *label = new QLabel();
        qreal scaleFactor = 1.25;

        label->setPixmap(QPixmap("qt-creator-logo.png"));
        label->setScaledContents(true);

        scrollArea->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Dark);
        scrollArea->setWidget(label);
        scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(false);

        l->addWidget(scrollArea);
        l->addWidget(btnZoomIn);
        l->addWidget(btnZoomOut);

        connect(btnZoomIn, &QPushButton::clicked, [label, scaleFactor](){
            label->resize(scaleFactor * label->size());
        });

        connect(btnZoomOut, &QPushButton::clicked, [label, scaleFactor](){
            label->resize((2 - scaleFactor) * label->size());
        });
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Viewer w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Note:** This code requires the [test image](https://i2.wp.com/emenda.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/qt-creator-logo.png) `qt-creator-logo.png` to be located in the build folder at runtime.

## Result

As written, this code produces the following result:

- non-scaled

[image: Window with a non-scaled image and two buttons]

- zoomed-in

[image: Window with a zoomed-in image and two buttons]

- zoomed-out

[image: Window with a zoomed-out image and two buttons]